# BaseEncoding to Generate Ids

Tags: java, algorithm, guava

How can i use com.google.common.base.BaseEncoding library to generate the unique ids.

```
public class google {

    static synchronized String generateIdforDCR()
    {
        return (String)BaseEncoding.base32().lowerCase().encode(UUID.randomUUID().toString().getBytes(Charsets.US_ASCII));

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(google.generateIdforDCR());
        }


    }

}
```

Output is :

```
gbsdgzrvgrsgclldgeytiljuga2wmllcmjstkllbmm3dszjymnrtcyjwga======
gi3gknbzg5tgiljrmq4tkljumqytmllbgfswkllbmiztim3fhbtdomldmq======
me4danrzgiyggllggu2dgljuhbrgillcmjswiljvgm2wimlemnrtqolgha======
meygmmrxgzsdgljqgbtgeljumm2wgllbmjrdsljrga3dgzrsguztgn3fmi======
```

I don't want such a big string but unique one.

Comment: Uhhh.. Looks unique to me.

Comment: You really should consider using name conventions. Class names starts with an uppercase letter. And there's no newline before the opening brace.

Answer (score 2):

UUID is 128 bits long, which means it gets base32 encoded into those 58 characters (you could strip the trailing equal signs). You could make it shorter by using base64, but that's no big win. If you want something shorter and guaranteed to be unique, you need a counter.

Something like

```
private static AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

static String generateIdforDCR() { // no need for synchronized
    return String.valueOf(counter.getAndIncrement());
}
```

should do. You could base64-encode it for even shorter output. Or simply use base36:

```
static String generateIdforDCR() { // no need for synchronized
    return Long.toString(counter.getAndIncrement(), Character.MAX_RADIX);
}
```